# how to clear textfield after message sent

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am trying to clear the text field after a button click and the sendMessage function. I keep running into errors and I cant figure it out. anyone have any ideas? Ive tried simply making a Bool variable in the first struct and toggling the value of it after the sendMesssages function. That causes an error of self is immutable and I cant access this var in the CustomMessageField where I have to do TextField.text = "" to clear it

```
struct MessagesField: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            CustomMessageField(placeholder: Text("Enter Your Message Here"), text: $message)
            
            Button {
                viewModel.sendMessages(withOtherUserUid: viewModeler.user.id ?? "", withText: message)
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "paperplane.fill")
            }
        }

    }
}


struct CustomMessageField: View{
    var placeholder: Text
    @Binding var text: String
    var editingChanged: (Bool) -> () = {_ in}
    var commit: () -> () = {}
    
    var body: some View{
        ZStack(alignment: .leading){
            if text.isEmpty{
                placeholder
                    .opacity(0.5)
            }
            TextField("", text: $text, onEditingChanged: editingChanged, onCommit: commit)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey there :) Could you provide in your question the things you've tried so far? Or maybe the errors you mentioned you had? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a @State var for the input. Once you have that you can easily set it to "" after sending:

```
struct MessagesField: View {
    
    @State private var message: String = "" // declare here

    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            CustomMessageField(placeholder: Text("Enter Your Message Here"), text: $message)
            
            Button {
                viewModel.sendMessages(withOtherUserUid: viewModeler.user.id ?? "", withText: message) 
                message = "" / reset here after send
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "paperplane.fill")
            }
        }
    }
}
```